# Can I start an IT career after the age of 30?

Tags: career-development, hiring-process, career-switch

My age is 30+, currently I'm doing a non IT job but I want to switch to software testing field. I'm learning manual testing along with api testing.

Is it really possible to start as a fresher now?
Should I continue to invest my time for this?

Comment: I'm 57. I started in the IT field at the age of 34. Is it possible? Yes.

Comment: Rather than asking "Can I" or "Should I", if you want fewer snarky comments, you should try editing it to be phrased more around asking for advice or warnings around the process of switching industries, and switching to IT, later in life.

Comment: We have a friend who got a Computer Science degree rather late in life and it didn't work out for him.  That's just one instance.  If you have the skills and motivation, you can do it.

Comment: How much effort are you willing to dedicate to this? To be a competent tester you should be at least an adequate coder, since that's what gives you insight into what needs to be tested plus the ability to describe the problem clearly enough to be actionable.

Comment: I started my literal career at 30. I was older when I graduated from high school by more than a year due to my birth month than anyone in my class. I took longer in college due to wanting to attend a Junior College before going to a traditional college. Once I moved to the traditional college I graduated with more than 150 credit hours, with multiple degrees. So it took me awhile to graduate, I got asked about it, but anyone that did were working at horrible companies that i would never accepted. I had no problem starting me career…completed my masters and working on another one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

When the economy is in great shape, most IT companies will be very eager to hire new workers and train them due to high business demand.

However, you should get some intern experience or good freelance experience to make your resume look great. Experience counts.